# Cross-browser compatibility problems with the position of the element

Tags: jquery, cross-browser

I have table id=target.
I need moved element in table.
I need to work with the object relative to the parent.

```
function StartVisual() {

    $("#man").attr('src', '/content/games/kamikaze2/go_right0.gif');
    $("#man").attr("style", "position:absolute;bottom:10px;left:70px;display:block;visibility:visible;");


    var left = $("#man").position().left;//man moved element
    alert(left);
}
```

in Opera I get 70, in Mozilla 300.
in the opera, I get the relative importance of absolute Mozilla

Help me, I need to get or absolute or relative, but equally in all browsers

**update:**
works in other browsers as well as in opera.

**answer:** I should use instead of the position was offset

Comment: Do you have this problem specifically with Opera 7 or it occurs with other browsers too...

Answer (score 0):

Try using a CSS Reset option. IMO [This one](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) by Eric Meyer is one of the most commonly used css resetting stylesheets. Resetting your css will give you a certain bit of control in preventing such idiosyncrasies.

Answer (score 0):

I should use instead of the position was offset